# Mixed-effects linear regression model using multiple independent measurements

Tags: matlab, linear-regression

I am trying to implement a linear mixed effect (LME) regression model for an x-ray imaging quality metric "CNR" (contrast-to-noise ratio) for which I measured for various tube potentials (kV) and filtration materials (Filter). CNR was measured for 3 consecutive slices so I have a standard deviation of the CNR from these independent measurements as well. I am wondering how I can incorporate these multiple independent measurements in my analysis. A representation of the data for a single measurement and my first attempt using fitlme is shown below. I tried looking at online resources but could not find an answer to my specific questions.

```
kV=[80 90 100 80 90 100 80 90 100]';
Filter={'Al','Al','Al','Cu','Cu','Cu','Ti','Ti','Ti'}';
CNR=[10 9 8 10.1 8.9 7.9 7 6 5]';
T=table(kV,Filter,CNR);
kV     Filter    CNR
___    ______    ___
 80     'Al'      10
 90     'Al'       9
100     'Al'       8
 80     'Cu'      10.1
 90     'Cu'       8.9
100     'Cu'       7.9
 80     'Ti'       7
 90     'Ti'       6
100     'Ti'       5
```

OUTPUT

```
Linear mixed-effects model fit by ML
Model information:
Number of observations               9
Fixed effects coefficients           4
Random effects coefficients          0
Covariance parameters                1

Formula:
CNR ~ 1 + kV + Filter

Model fit statistics:
AIC        BIC        LogLikelihood    Deviance
-19.442    -18.456    14.721           -29.442 

Fixed effects coefficients (95% CIs):
Name           Estimate    SE           pValue          
'(Intercept)'  18.3        0.17533      1.5308e-09    
'kV'          -0.10333     0.0019245    4.2372e-08  
'Filter_Cu'   -0.033333    0.03849     -0.86603    
'Filter_Ti'   -3           0.03849     -77.942    

Random effects covariance parameters (95% CIs):
Group: Error
Name             Estimate    Lower     Upper   
'Res Std'        0.04714     0.0297    0.074821
```

Questions/Issues with current implementation:

How is the fixed effects coefficients for '(Intercept)' with P=1.53E-9 interpreted?

I only included fixed effects. Should the standard deviation of the ROI measurements somehow be incorporated into the random effects as well?

How do I incorporate the three independent measurements of CNR for three consecutive slices for a give kV/filter combination? Should I just add more rows to the table "T"? This would result in a total of 27 observations.